# How to unscrew this stuck screw inside a pan handle

Tags: screws, stuck

I have a pan that is rendered into useless because of the coating peeling off.
So I tried to remove the plastic handle from both sides. There are 2 screws in both sides, and this last one stuck and cannot be removed. The "tooth" is also wearing off due to the number of attempts to remove it.

Is there any effective way to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Common ways are penetrating oil, heat, and the last is drilling.  Might just need to remove the head, instead of the screw.  If the handle is going to be toss also, a hammer would probably remove it from the pan.

Comment: What is the reason for removing the handle? Are you attempting to recycle the metal, or salvage the handle for some other use, or what?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I mean to recycle the handle because local policy require to remove all the non-metal part or they won't accept the recycle item/

Comment: I have tried @crip659's suggestion that by using penetrating oil but I didn't have so I tried WD40 instead. It didn't work then I try to heat up the pan to see if it help to loose the screw, it did't work also. Then I tried to drill but the hand drill seems cannot penetrating the screw or the progress is very slow. So I have no other way but considering using a minus screwdriver to lever it up attempting to loose it. But eventually the plastic break apart. The screw still stuck on the pan and I tried to unscrew it curiously but it didn't move either. It seems to be stuck firmly or become part

Comment: Throw it in the trash.

Comment: There's an old saying "there's no engineering problem that can't be solved with a big enough hammer".  If you hit the handle with a big enough hammer, you may never need to remove the screw.

Comment: @SteveWellens While throwing is extremely easily to do, while if we could do a bit to reduce the harm and waste to the earth, I am personally willing to spend some efforts to recycle. I have thrown a lot of things previously while I was ignorant to the value of things without a sense of treasure and thanksgiving to them. So as time goes by and learning from the world, there are many alternatives to throwing a still usable or recyclable item.

Comment: @西門正CodeGuy  So you've used chemicals and energy to "recycle" an inert metal worth a few pennies.   I think you've already done more harm to the environment than good.

Comment: @SteveWellens Thanks for taking time to share your thought.

Comment: @SimonB It also sounds worth to try, I will take it for reference for the future cases. Thanks for sharing. I have tried to take closeup macro photo to understand the reason. It seems that only this screw is somehow rusted inside with the whole screw showing brown in color, not sure if it is really rust or oil because it is fry pan used to be.

Answer (score 1):

It may be too late if you've already started drilling, but for stubborn screws I've always found a manual impact wrench (with a screwdriver tip inserted)  is the best tool. When you hit it with a hammer, it not only twists to remove the screw, but it drives the bit deeper into the screw head, minimizing stripping the screw head. Here's a picture:

[image]

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try but will take it as reference if I meet the same situation in the future. Thanks for the suggestion.